# Evaluate double integral $\iint x^2 \cos(x^2-xy)\,dx\,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Evaluate double integral $$\iint x^2 \cos(x^2-xy)\,dx\,dy$$ where region is bounded by sides of triangle whose vertices are $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$.

I used order $dy\,dx$ to evaluate it. I becomes unsolvable after this. Where i am wrong?

It reduces to $$\int_{0}^{1} -x\sin(2x^2-x) + x\sin(x^2)$$

**EDIT**

As per request of user Jester Tran

My double integral was $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-x} x^2 \cos(x^2-xy)\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: how will $dxdy$ work here?

Comment: Can we see your working out for $dy dx$ manipulation?

Comment: @JesterTran question edited

Comment: Presumably, you have used Fubini's Theorem. We would like to see an expression in the form $\int \int f(x,y) \color{red}{dy dx}$ before integration.

Comment: won't it be $\sin$ ?

Comment: @JesterTran edited question

Comment: avz2611 found your error but I've reduced this problem down to integrating $\cos (2x^2 - x)$ w.r.t $x$ which doesn't look do-able.

Comment: yes it's not solvable by hand computer is needed

Answer (score 2):

try solving this integral
$$\int_{o}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}x^2\cos({x^2-xy})dy dx$$ your final fom contains $\cos$ where as it should be $sin$ as far as solving the integral goes you can take the term inside $\sin$ as $t$ for 2 different integrals
solution : $$\int_{0}^{1}-x\sin{(2x^2-x)+\int_{0}^{1}x\sin{x^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}-(x-1/4)\sin{(2x^2-x)}+\int_{0}^{1}x\sin{x^2}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{4}\sin{(2x^2-x)}$$
last integral does not have an elementary solution

Comment: i had this question on my paper of multi variable calculus. I think question is wrong bcos in class we had never encountered unsolvable integral

Comment: it's all right , if you got the final form , your prof should give you the marks you deserve.

Comment: @Gathdi If the question was $x^2 \cos (x^2 \color{red}{+} xy)$, then it can be done!

Comment: But he didnot give me marks

Comment: @Gathdi Why didn't he give you any marks? Please appeal.

Comment: @JesterTran yes i thought so during my test

Comment: yep jester is right square term is removed , so its solvable

Comment: I do not know why and i can't ask why because i am private student.